# How to patch function's return value, but still get it's side effects in python unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, side-effects

I want to patch a function's return value in a unittest (it is originally expensive to evaluate), but still test its side effect (setting an attribute). The code looks sth like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        self.my_attribute = None
    
    # this function returns some string but also sets the value of self.my_attribute
    def my_function():
        self.my_attribute = 'sth'
        return 'sth_else'

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch(MyClass.my_function, return_value='test_value')
    def test_my_function(self, mock_function):
        #when
        my_instance = MyClass()
        my_return = my_instance.my_function()
        #then
        self.assertEqual(my_instance.my_attribute, 'sth')
```

However, since the function is patched it doesn't run (right?) and so there is no side effect either. Is there a way to force the side effect to show up?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Either you replace the function with something else (like a mock), or you call the whole function (directly, or as a side effect). You cannot patch away specific parts of the function body (like the return statement - which is nothing special, and can appear anywhere in the function, or appear multipke times). If you have the possibility to refactor the tested code, you can factor out the expansive calculation, which you can then patch.